# Allowing user to configure GWT app look and feel

Tags: gwt

My app contains 3 views ( for now ) each button has a few buttons ,  dropdowns etc.
I set the look and feel of a button using widget.setStyle( xxx )
What approach should I use to give the user the option to change the look and feel of buttons, fonts etc across each view.  My initial thoughts are that when I call widget.setStyle( xxx ) ,  xxx will have to be some value pulled back from a static class which in turn has been set by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of approaches to do this .

1)If its a lite weight process .

use the setStyle with your setings class values of user .

2)If there are number of changes

After settings saved reaload the app and append according css  files through JSNI methods.